# Chrome Autofill not filling correct input

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Bit confusing and could not find any related issues online. As can be seen in the screenshot, when using the Chrome Autofill it is filling up the wrong input, even though the input have different ids.

This is using knockout template but not sure if its related.

HTML code for Billing Address

```
<input data-bind="value: $data.editor.SearchHouseNumber, uniqueId: $data.editor.SearchHouseNumber, valueUpdate: ['blur', 'afterkeydown', 'onload'], css: $data.editor.labelClass" maxlength="100" name="customerSearchHouseNumber" placeholder="House no." size="24" type="text" value="" title="" id="fld2">
```

HTML code for Delivery Address

```
<input data-bind="value: $data.editor.SearchHouseNumber, uniqueId: $data.editor.SearchHouseNumber, valueUpdate: ['blur', 'afterkeydown', 'onload'], css: $data.editor.labelClass" maxlength="100" name="customerSearchHouseNumber" placeholder="House no." size="24" type="text" value="" title="" id="fld17">
```

[image: Google Auto Complete Issue]

Comment: Are you writing an extension to autofill the values?  Or is something else autofilling them for you?

Comment: No extensions or plugins added. this is happening on different computers as well, so its not related to my environment or chrome version.


Also, the inputs in the delivery address part are set to display:none on when the page is loaded and are only visible when change address button is clicked.


The client still wants this feature on chrome and they don't wont to disable this.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) which parts you are writing, and which parts something else is (incorrectly) doing for you.  Are you creating the backend, and chrome isn't filling in the data correctly?  This doesn't sound like a chrome-*extension*, which is the only tag you've used.  You may want to use the tags [tag:google-chrome] and [tag:autofill] (and probably one of the knockout tags - I don't know enough to figure out which one).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Chrome actually implements the full [autocomplete spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofill-field) here, which means you should be able to specify which type of data Chrome should use to fill in the fields. Therefore, you can add the following attributes to your inputs:
`autocomplete="billing street-address"` and `autocomplete="shipping street-address"`, and Chrome will likely be able to supply the correct values.

Note that `street-address` designation can take multiline values (as per spec), so you may prefer `address-line1`.

**Example:**

```
<input name="billing_address" id="fld2" autocomplete="billing street-address">
```